# Requests to Apollo Express Server aren't going through the middleware

Tags: javascript, graphql, middleware, apollo-server

I'm trying to create an app with Apollo Express Server and GraphQL. I have the Apollo server's context set to a function that should check if the user is authorized/logged in, but it seems like the request isn't actually going through that context function. When I attempt to send a request to the server via the Apollo studio, I get the following error:
`Context creation failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'token')`

I had a near-identical set-up in a different app, the only differences being in the exact responses sent out from authMiddleware, and I'm not sure what's gone wrong. I am definitely including the appropriate headers when working in the studio.

Edit: SOLVED. There were two issues:

1. The arguments for authMiddleware needed to be destructured - ({req, res, next}), not (req, res, next).
2. There's no other middleware functions, so the server was crashing upon reaching the next() call.

---

Relevant code:

server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const {ApolloServer} = require('apollo-server-express');
const path = require('path');

const {typeDefs, resolvers} = require('./schemas');
const {authMiddleware} = require('./utils/auth');
const db = require('./config/connection');

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    context: authMiddleware
});
const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.json());

const startApolloServer = async (typeDefs, resolvers) => {
    await server.start();
    server.applyMiddleware({app});
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build')));
};

// frontend isn't set up yet
// app.get('*', (req, res) => {
//      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/build// /index.html'));
// });

db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
        console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
        console.log(
            `Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}${server.graphqlPath}`
        );
    });
});

startApolloServer(typeDefs, resolvers);
```

utils/auth.js:

```
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require('dotenv').config();

const secret = process.env.JWT_SECRET;
const expiration = '2h';

module.exports = {
  // function for our authenticated routes
  authMiddleware: function (req, res, next) {
    // allows token to be sent via query, body, or headers
    // if i remove the req.body.token and req.query.token options, i still get an error -
    // Context creation failed: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'headers')
    let token = req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers.authorization;

    // ["Bearer", "<tokenvalue>"]
    if (req.headers.authorization) {
      token = token.split(' ').pop().trim();
    }

    if (!token) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'You have no token!' });
    }

    // verify token and get user data out of it
    try {
      const { data } = jwt.verify(token, secret, { maxAge: expiration });
      req.user = data;
    } catch {
      console.log('Invalid token');
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'invalid token!' });
    }

    // send to next endpoint
    next();
  },
  signToken: function ({ username, email, _id }) {
    const payload = { username, email, _id };

    return jwt.sign({ data: payload }, secret, { expiresIn: expiration });
  },
};
```